# Error al ordenar tabla por nombre

Tags: php

Tengo una tabla con resultados la cual pretendo que al *clickear* una imagen se ordene por su nombre en forma ascendente, pero me salta error y no sé por qué. Les dejo mi código y la línea en donde salta el error (este es el tipo de error: Undefined variable:).

Mi código:

```
    if(isset($_POST['reg'])) {
    $q=$conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['reg']);
    if ($q == "Marcas") {
    $orden = isset($_GET['ORD']) ? $_GET['ORD'] : "id";
        $query = "SELECT id, nombre_m FROM marcas ORDER By $orden ";
        $buscarreg=$conexion->query($query);
        if ($buscarreg->num_rows > 0){
            $tabla.=
            '<table class="table">
                <tr class="bg-primary">
                        <td>
                        <a href="buscando.php?ORD=nombre_m">
                            <img class="orden" src="../4.imagenes/up.png" /></a>
                        Id
                        </td>
                        <td>Nombre</td>
                </tr>';
```

Comment: Te recomiendo usar Data Table, es un plug in que te permite mostrar los datos en formato tabla con excelentes características como filtro para búsqueda, ordenar de forma ascendente o descendente haciendo click en el encabezado de las columnas, paginación, etc... Te ahorrará mucho tiempo. [Aquí la documentación oficial](https://datatables.net/)

Answer (score 0):

`$orden` no siempre estará definida, por lo que debes asignarle un valor y no puede ser vacío ya que depende un order de sql en esa variable

```
// puedes usar un operador ternario
$orden = isset($_GET['ORD']) ? $_GET['ORD'] : "id";
```

Comment: Gracias, pero ahora tengo un nuevo problema y es que pierdo el valor de $_POST["reg"] y no puedo ver mi tabla

Comment: ¿Que fue lo que hiciste? No deberia afectar el get

Comment: Edité mi pregunta con mi nuevo código.Ese código pertenece a un buscador en tiempo real, que al seleccionar una marca (de ahí el POST) muestra la tabla, al ser un href recarga la página y al ser recargada pierde el POST por lo cual no muestra la tabla. Pensé en mandar el $_POST[reg]  en el href, pero no sé cómo se hace (si quiera sé si se puede).